# Android AsyncTask keeps return opposite value

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got a problem with AsyncTask at Android Studio. What I am trying to do is before I create a new user, I am checking if the username and email exist in my database. Here is the part where I call the create AsyncTask:

```
new SignupAsyncTask(getBaseContext()).execute(userModel);
if(SignupAsyncTask.successCheck == false){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(SignupAsyncTask.successCheck == true){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Inside my AsyncTask, I am getting all user. Then I perform a loop to check if there is any matching username or password. If there is, I set the successCheck to false.

```
public class SignupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Integer, Boolean> {
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    DB_User userCtrl = new DB_User();
    Context context;
    public static boolean successCheck = false;

    public SignupAsyncTask(){}

    public SignupAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(User... params) {
        try {
            list = userCtrl.getAllUser();
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                User userObj = list.get(i);
                if(params[0].getUserName().equals(userObj.getUserName())){
                    successCheck = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (params[0].getEmail().equals(userObj.getEmail())){
                    successCheck = false;
                    break;
                } else{
                    successCheck = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(successCheck == true){
            userCtrl.SignupUser(params[0]);
        }
        return successCheck;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }
}
```

The problem that I have encountered now is for the first time when I am testing with a non-duplicate username and email, it can insert into database but somehow the toast printed out 'Failed'.

Then, when I try with another duplicate record, it does not insert into database as I set my username and email to be UNIQUE but the toast is printing out 'Success'.

It is operated in the opposite way as my code logic. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

```
public class SignupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Integer, Boolean> {
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
DB_User userCtrl = new DB_User();
Context lcontext;
public static boolean successCheck = false;

public SignupAsyncTask(){}

public SignupAsyncTask(Context context){
    lcontext = context;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(User... params) {
    try {
        list = userCtrl.getAllUser();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            User userObj = list.get(i);
            if(params[0].getUserName().equals(userObj.getUserName())){
                successCheck = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (params[0].getEmail().equals(userObj.getEmail())){
                successCheck = false;
                break;
            } else{
                successCheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return successCheck;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    if(successCheck)
    {
        //userCtrl.SignupUser(userobject);
        Log.d("Check","Ran Success");
        Toast.makeText(lcontext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else {
        Log.d("Check","Ran Fail");
        Toast.makeText(lcontext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

}
```

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(Double result)` .. this doesn't look right. I think that should actually be `protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)` based on the other signatures in your AsyncTask.

Comment: log "list" and "params"... and also provide this

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), as its name, is an asynchronous task. You need to test the result in your **SignupAsyncTask** class.

Add the logic to your AsyncTask `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
  if(result == false){
    // Process if false
  } else if(result == true){
    // Process if true
  }
}
```

Because you can't access UI thread from SignupAsyncTask (where your class is not a member class of your caller class), you need to define an interface as listener mechanism in your caller class to receive the result from your AsyncTask. So whenever there is a change in data, it will inform the caller who implements the interface.

Something like:

```
public interface OnSuccessCheckReceived{
  void onSuccessCheckReceived(boolean isSuccess);
}
```

Then you add  the callback interface to SignupAsyncTask:

```
public class SignupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Integer, Boolean> {
  ...

  OnSuccessCheckReceived callBack;
  public SignupAsyncTask(){}

  public SignupAsyncTask(Context context, OnSuccessCheckReceived callBack){
    this.context = context;
    this.callBack = callBack;
  }

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    //if(result == false){
    //  // Process if false
    //  callBack.onSuccessCheckReceived(false); // Tell the caller 
    //} else if(result == true){
    //  // Process if true
    //}

    // a more compact code
    callBack.onSuccessCheckReceived(result); // Tell the caller 
  }
```

Then you need to implement the listener interface to your caller class.
Something like:

```
public class YourCallerActivity implements OnSuccessCheckReceived {
  ...
  @Override 
  public void onSuccessCheckReceived(boolean isSuccess) {
    if(isSuccess){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you must call your AsyncTask with:

```
// this is pointing to your implemented interface.
new SignupAsyncTask(getBaseContext(), this).execute(userModel);
```

---

Suggestion,

Better if you don't add a **context** to an **AsyncTask**, because when your app terminated and AsyncTask not yet finished its job, your AsyncTask **will throw an Error** because the previous context its pointing is already gone.

So you need to change your SignupAsyncTask constructor to:

```
public SignupAsyncTask(OnSuccessCheckReceived callBack){
  //this.context = context; Remove this.
  this.callBack = callBack;
}
```

and call the SignupAsyncTask  with:

```
new SignupAsyncTask(this).execute(userModel);
```

---

UPDATE

As @trooper pointing out, you need to change your:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

}
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){

}
```

So to tell the caller class, you need to tell about the result:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
  // This is a more compact code that your previous code.
  callBack.onSuccessCheckReceived(result); // Tell the caller 
}
```

based on the other signatures in your AsyncTask.

Comment: But currently I am doing all the logic in doInBackground(), so does that mean I have to move all the logic into onPostExecute()?

Comment: No, you just need to send the result in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic inside `onPostExecute()` :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    if(successCheck){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask** executes asynchronously i.e., It does not run on a Main thread. It spawns a separate thread known as Worker thread, executes its logic and then post back the results onto the Main thread.

### Edit 1

Change your code as below :

```
public class SignupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Integer, Boolean> {
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    DB_User userCtrl = new DB_User();
    Context context;
    public static boolean successCheck = false;
    User user = null;

    public SignupAsyncTask(){}

    public SignupAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(User... params) {
        try {
            user = params[0];
            list = userCtrl.getAllUser();
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                User userObj = list.get(i);
                if(user.getUserName().equals(userObj.getUserName())){
                    successCheck = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (user.getEmail().equals(userObj.getEmail())){
                    successCheck = false;
                    break;
                } else{
                    successCheck = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return successCheck;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(result){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Call SignupUser Code Here...
            if(user != null) {
                userCtrl.SignupUser(user);   
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not even printing out the toast now. Sorry but how do I modify it accordingly?

Comment: Just to check with you that because I am passing a User object from UI as parameter, so how do I grab the parameter from onPostExcute?

Comment: @2dollar20cents : You can declare `userModel` as instance variable.

Comment: He made a small mistake in checking the boolean flag. He should check if result is true not successCheck((which should be local variable not global). However, the big problem I see here is you being completely unrelated with AsyncTask and, on top of that, you did not read much on the documentation page. Start by taking your time and read the async task, take a small example(like the one from above) and go step by step with the debugger. Questions like "toast is now showing" can be checked via debugger.

Comment: @MonishKamble Hi, sorry one more question, for the getBaseContext() right, it is throwing me error message so I changed it to (RegisterActivity)context as currently in my AsyncTask class, I already declared a context variable, so to avoid using that context, I cast it to my Activity class. However, it is throwing me error messages. Do you have any ideas how  to solve this?

Comment: @2dollar20cents : You can use `context` which you have declared inside `SignupAsyncTask`. If this is not want you are asking for, please specify the line number in code.

Comment: Alright thanks so much. But there is one more problem, because I am passing the user object as into this async task as params[0], but how do I call the params[0] inside doPostExecute()? I declared another local user object and set to it using userObj = params[0]; However, it is still not working. Any ideas? Sorry for keep troubling you.

Comment: @2dollar20cents : Please post your updated code so that I can get a clear idea and would be able to suggest you a solution.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please help me take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code like this

```
    private ArrayList<User> list;
        private DB_User userCtrl;
        private Context context;
        private SendResponse mRes;

        public SignupAsyncTask(Context context,SendResponse res){
            this.context = context;
            userCtrl = new DB_User();
            list = new ArrayList<User>();
            mRes = res;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(User... params) {
            try {
                list = userCtrl.getAllUser();
                for(User userObj:userCtrl.getAllUser()){
                    if(params[0].getUserName().equals(userObj.getUserName())
                            || params[0].getEmail().equals(userObj.getEmail()))
                       return false;
                }else{
                    userCtrl.SignupUser(params[0]);
                      return true;
}
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){


                //notify through interface to activity or fragment wherever you want to
                //mRes.sendResponse(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }
```

Comment: The params inside onPostExecute. How do I pass it from doInbackground to onPostExecute?

Comment: doInBackground has a return type Boolean, which passes the result to onPostExecute. Lifecycle of Async task is like this pre => donInBackground => postExecute and whatever you return in background is present in postExecute. Please accept the answer it this works

Comment: But the params[0] in onPostExecute is not declared. How should I fix that?

Comment: So at the onPostExecute, I call the sendResponse(result) back to my boundary. Then at the activity how do I grab the response pass back and print out the toast accordingly?

Comment: I have already created the interface for that. Please see that, it will notify the activity or fragment.

Comment: Sorry but where is the interface?

Comment: private SendResponse mRes; this is the interface it will be implemented in your activity and this would be passed in Async task .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126072/discussion-between-sinistro-and-2-dollar-20-cents).